# Is it best practice to always capitalize class file names in PHP, and other languages?

Tags: object-oriented, naming, class

I ask because I've seen a couple of OO PHP tutorials which do not adhere to this, but to me it just makes sense. It makes it easy to instantly see if a file is a class or not, if non-class files all use lowercase names.

Comment: Related: [Naming classes, methods, functions and variables](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/149303/25936)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a naming convention question and whilst it is a good meta question it seems to have been well covered with this [StackOverflow question from Dec 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20130812021305/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332831/best-practices-for-naming-conventions).

Basically, some languages have prescribed naming conventions (e.g. Java) whereas others (the majority) have evolved and are mixed to the point of *Programmer's Holy Wars*.

Comment: To bad that link doesn't work anymore... that is why link answers are bad, even links to SO don't always stay live.

Comment: I have added a WebArchive link to bring it back to life.

Answer (score 1):

My 2c:

If the language doesn't force any conventions, and this includes things like indentation (not just naming).  Then the important thing is consistency.  Consistency is far more important than the choice of a good convention.

The existing answer answers your actual question.